# Successive Event Not Working On Element Created From Previous Event

Tags: javascript, html

The function that I am trying to achieve:

*Input[type="submit"] click should create another button within a paragraph, and when I click on this new button again, it reverts back to the input form.*

Here's the code:

```
inputPar = document.querySelector("#oldpar .myText");
oldPar = document.querySelector("#oldpar"); 
newPar = document.querySelector("#newpar");
function writePar(e) {
    newPar.innerHTML = htmlEntities(inputPar.value) + '<br/>' + '<button 
       class="myBtn">Click Me</button>';
    newPar.style.display="block";
    oldPar.style.display = "none";
    e.stopPropagation();
}
function revertMe(e) {
    oldPar.style.display="block";
    newPar.style.display="none";
    e.stopPropagation();
}
var submitPar = document.getElementById("oldpar").querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
submitPar.addEventListener("click", writePar); 

var myBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");
myBtn.addEventListener("click", revertMe);
```

And here's the HTML code that I am trying to use.

```
<p id="oldpar">
   <input class="myText" type="text" maxlength="450"/>
   <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit My Value"/></p>
<p id="newpar"></p>
```

Am I wrong to think that second click event is called on an element which is already being created by the first click event?

Is there a different flow of call of listeners?

The console shows that `myBtn.addEventListener is not a function`. Why so?

Comment: `myBtn[0].addEventListener("click", revertMe);` try this once. because `var myBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");` is give you a collection

Comment: @AlivetoDie nopes, still not working!

Comment: does `myBtn.addEventListener` give you an error in the **developer** tools console? are there other errors perhaps?

Comment: by the way : `document.getElementById("oldpar").querySelector('input[type="submit"]');` is just `document.querySelector('#oldpar input[type="submit"]');`

Comment: the problem is that the button created in `writePar` does not exist when you try to add the event listener to it

Comment: can you please post whole code.how's you are calling your  `writePar(e) ` and `revertMe(e)` functions?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Here's the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/schttrj/pen/PmevxY).

Comment: @JaromandaX the error is myBtn.addEventListener is not a function. Umm..one thing, the button does exist when it's called, doesn't it? It would have already been created by that time from the previous click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button doesn't exist at the time you try to register event listener on it.

One of the solutions would be to register the click event when the button actually exists, by setting it inside `writePar()` method, after injecting the `.myBtn` into DOM, like so:

```
function writePar(e) {
  newPar.innerHTML = htmlEntities(inputPar.value) + '<br/>' + '<button class="myBtn">Click Me</button>';
  newPar.style.display="block";
  oldPar.style.display = "none";
  var myBtn = document.querySelector(".myBtn");
  myBtn.addEventListener("click", revertMe);
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWrqpa)

---

Another solution would be to use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) on the closest *static* element (in your case it would be `#newpar`). F.ex:

```
//var myBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");
//myBtn.addEventListener("click", revertMe);

newPar.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if (e.target && e.target.matches(".myBtn")) {
    revertMe(e);
  }
});
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVLooW)

Comment: Thanks so much, Artur. Work like magic! For others who are facing the same problem, here's an [article](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) that might help you.